# Unexpected C string definition behaviour

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals

As far as I know the below code should not work. Yet, somehow this is OK on my compiler. Please could someone explain.

```
int main()
{
    char *string;
    string = "Goo";
}
```

Comment: **Why** did you expect it not to "work"??? This is the most important part of the question that you somehow omitted.

Comment: Code should be `const char *string;`.  When `const` was introduced, that "should be" was not specified as it was expected to break too much prior code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As far as I know the below code should not work*

I'm afraid, your information is wrong.

```
char *string;
string = "Goo";
```

is perfectly valid. This is basically,

1. Define a `char` pointer `string`.
2. Put the base address of the *string literal* `"Goo"` into `string`.

However, instead of being a `char` pointer, if `string` would have been an array, then this would not have been possible as array's cannot be *assigned* (except definition time though brace enclosed list).

Comment: Plus for legacy reasons, "Goo" is not `const` unless your compiler is gcc and you explicitly tell it to make them const.

Comment: @Medinoc ....(just for completeness), but, (attempt to) modifying them is anyway  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `-Wwrite-strings` is what changes string literals to have `const char *`

Comment: @o11c Nice one, but that's maybe again `gcc` specific, IMHO, not standard `C`. Hope I'm not misunderstood. :-)

Comment: Mostly I was extending @Medinoc 's comment. But IMHO since the only standard-compliant compilers implement a significant subset of GCC extensions, GCC-specific extensions are reasonably allowed.

Comment: @o11c: It changes them to `const char[N]`, not to `const char *`. However, this is a violation of C language spec. In C string literals are not const-qualified.

Comment: "... if string would have been an array, then this would not ...". How about a _compound literal_?

Comment: @Olaf Good Morning Sir !! Yeah, you're right, but by saying "this" , I only meant this particular assignment, in current form. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input Sourav + others. I realise that I was confusing char* with char x[]!

Comment: (Good day to you, too Sir) Ok, I think I got your point. Yes a simple assignment is not possible, you would need `memcpy()` then.

Comment: @AnT: You are right, this is non-standard. That is a gcc-specific warning/modifier (it should not start with `-W` actually. It is not included in `-Wall` for that reason. However, as for embedded systems one very likely wants to pack string literals into Flash, this is a very welcome feature. It also warns if breaking const-correctness by assigning such a literal to a non-`const char *.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, done! I'm still getting used to this whole stackexchange thing. Thanks for your help!